# access Array data In Blade view

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-api

I have an external API that returns array data and I want to display it in my blade view
have tried like this but I'm getting an error

```
    <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <table class="">
    @foreach($deviceStatus as $dt)
    <tr>
      <th>DEVICE NUMBER</th>
      <td>{{$dt['mDeviceID']}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

error

```
Undefined index: mDeviceID
```

Array Data

```
          array:12 [▼
      7200408497 => array:4 [▼
        "payload" => array:2 [▼
          0 => array:44 [▼
            "id" => 4484
            "position" => array:2 [▶]
            "mDeviceID" => "7200408497"
             "slave" => array:2 [▶]
            "payload" => ""
            "deviceDetails" => array:9 [▶]
            "isActivated" => true
            "serial" => "7200408497"
            "isDeleted" => false
            "status" => 0
          ]
          1 => array:44 [▶]
        ]
        "count" => 2
        "total" => 0
      ]
      7200408223 => array:4 [▶]
```

How can I access that data in array data?

Comment: Does `{{$dt['payload'][0]['position']['mDeviceID']}}` work?

Comment: YES, sir this is works `{{$dt['payload'][0]['mDeviceID']}}`,, let me test the one you updated

Comment: If that works it's fine, I think you don't need the `['position']` in there, looked like `mDeviceID` is inside `position` but looking at it now I think it is not. Was a little confused by the output of that array

Comment: do we need to add the `[$key]` instead of `[0] `? and how about this 
   "slave" => array:2 [▼
                               0 => array:10 [▼
                                 "sDeviceId" => "E0171E07F4"  
                               ]
                               1 => array:10 [▼
                                 "sDeviceId" => "E0171E07F9"
                                 
                               ]
                             ]

Comment: @brombeer, can you advice on slave ?

Comment: Don't get this the wrong way but you should really learn how to traverse arrays in PHP. Just follow the structure of that array. It most likely is something like `{{$dt['payload'][0]['slave'][0]['sDeviceID']}}`. If `slave` is an array and you want to get all children use `foreach` to iterate over it. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <table class="">
    @foreach($deviceStatus as $dt)
       @foreach($dt['payload'] as $dts)
         <tr>
           <th>DEVICE NUMBER</th>
          <td>{{$dts['mDeviceID']}}</td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
   @endforeach
  </table>
```